# How to Lock Only the Current ADODB.Recordset Instead of the Whole Page (or Table) in VBA/Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb, recordset

I want to lock just the current ADODB recordset (but not the page or the entire table) of a multi-user system developed in VBA/Access so that any other user that opens the same recordset cannot edit one recordset position already in edit mode in some other user computer. I want to avoid 2 o more users editing the same record position (eg: more than one user editing the registration of the same employee).

I tested the folowing code, unsuccessfully:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim dbcon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim recrdst As ADODB.Recordset

    Set recrdst = New ADODB.Recordset

    recrdst.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    recrdst.LockType = adLockPessimistic

    Set dbcon = New ADODB.Connection

    dbcon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=C:\Família\Alex Borges\Companies\Imobiliária Halex Tiago\Estudos\Sistema Multi-Usuário\Servidor.mdb;"

    recrdst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblDependentes", dbcon

    Set Me.Recordset = recrdst

    Set recrdst = Nothing
    Set dbcon = Nothing
End Sub
```

I also tested the folowing code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim dbcon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim recrdst As ADODB.Recordset

    Set dbcon = New ADODB.Connection
    dbcon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=C:\Família\Alex Borges\Companies\Imobiliária Halex Tiago\Estudos\Sistema Multi-Usuário\Servidor.mdb;"

    Set recrdst = New ADODB.Recordset
    recrdst.ActiveConnection = dbcon
    recrdst.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    recrdst.LockType = adLockPessimistic
    recrdst.CursorLocation = adUseServer

    recrdst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblDependentes", dbcon

    Set Me.Recordset = recrdst

    Set recrdst = Nothing
    Set dbcon = Nothing
End Sub
```

my Access version is 2007. on Access/Options/Advanced, I changed the default record locking to "edited record".

thanks in advance.